# Unity - When launching the built game .exe, the window shrinks everytime?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Every time I run the .exe to my game, the window shrinks every time. In Project Settings, it is defaulted to Windowed at 960x540. Under Standalone Player Options, I have User Player Log, Visible in Background, and Allow Fullscreen Switch, and Use DXGI Flip Model Swapchain for D3D11 all checked off with supported Aspect Ratios of 4:3, 5:4, 16:10 and 16:9.

Here's an example of what happens:

1st Launch: window size is intended 960x540, play game for however long, close game

2nd Launch: window size now looks slightly smaller? maybe im seeing things, play game, close game

3rd Launch: window size is definitely smaller and now everything is getting pixelated because of how small the window size is

4th, 5th, 6th launch and now the window size is only big enough to show the minimize, and close buttons

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but has the cause to this behaviour ever been found? The exact same thing was reported by a tester of my game.

Comment: Suuuper weird. This just happened to me but still unresolved. Its just getting smaller and smaller...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is happening but the temporary fix is to select the window and press alt + enter to maximize the window

Comment: yes that works but now that it's full screen, it is no longer the intended resolution, making it VERY pixelated